# UISlider subclass for custom thumb location and thumb image?

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

Is it possible to implement above slider by subclassing UISlider?
I want slider thumb move to edges but there is some space left.
I have achieved custom position by overriding following methods but now thumb is not responding to touch events.

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:IMG_SLIDER_THUMB] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (CGRect)thumbRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds trackRect:(CGRect)rect value:(float)value {
    UIImage* image = self.currentThumbImage;

    CGRect thumbRect = [super thumbRectForBounds:bounds trackRect:rect value:value];

return CGRectMake(thumbRect.origin.x, rect.origin.y+2, image.size.width, image.size.height);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented above by subclassing UISlider and for touch event issue I added height constraint to slider in storyboard to increase bounds at runtime. Following is the code to move slider to edges and custom thumb location:

```
//Get thumb rect for larger track rect than actual to move slider to edges
-(CGRect)thumbRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds trackRect:(CGRect)rect value:(float)value {
    UIImage *image = self.currentThumbImage;

    rect.origin.x -= SLIDER_OFFSET;
    rect.size.width += (SLIDER_OFFSET*2);
    CGRect thumbRect = [super thumbRectForBounds:bounds trackRect:rect value:value];
    return CGRectMake(thumbRect.origin.x, rect.origin.y+2, image.size.width, image.size.height);
}

//Make track rect smaller than bounds
-(CGRect)trackRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds  {
    bounds.origin.x += SLIDER_OFFSET;
    bounds.size.width -= (SLIDER_OFFSET*2);
    CGRect trackRect = [super trackRectForBounds:bounds];

    return CGRectMake(trackRect.origin.x, trackRect.origin.y, trackRect.size.width, trackRect.size.height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the code is wrong. 
First, you should get the CGRect of the custom view like this:
CGRect oldRect = [super thumbRectForBounds:bounds trackRect:rect value:value];
Than, change the oldRect.x and oldRect.y ,get NewRect
The last , return the NewRect.